# Error log when running the unit test cases. How to test ehcache using mockito?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

The controller class:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/isverified/{msisdn}", produces = {
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE }
)
@ApiOperation(value = "Is Verified", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> isVerified(@PathVariable(value = "msisdn") String msisdn) 
     throws Exception 

    GcInitResponse verifiedResponse = gcinitService.isVerified(msisdn);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(verifiedResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The test class:

```
public void testIsVerified() throws Exception {

    //fail("Not yet implemented");
    String msisdn = "212361253";  

    mockMvc.perform(get("/gcinit/v1/isverified/{msisdn}",msisdn))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.verified", is("true")))
        .andDo(print());  
}
```

> Error
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; >nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cached value is not of >required type [java.lang.String]: null

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cached value is not of required type [java.lang.String]: null

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the error there. Code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: okay sure.......

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  The controller class that you've shown doesn't actually have any of its own logic, so there's not much point in trying to write any kind of unit test for it.  I don't know where ehcache fits into this, or why you want to use Mockito to test it.  What kind of help are you expecting someone to provide?

Comment: Can I know how to write unit test case for the controller above using J-unit mockito?

Comment: Well, for a unit test case, you'd inject a mock for `gcinitService`, stub out `isVerified`, and assert that the response inside the returned `ResponseEntity` matches the value you stubbed.  But there's absolutely no point in doing that.  Don't waste your time.